# PHP Echo Inline CSS

Tags: php, css

I would like to set an inline css background image using a variable using a PHP echo.

```
echo "<div id='wtile' style='background:url(\'http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/". $row["icon_url_large"]. "\');'> 
    <div id='name'> ". $row["market_hash_name"]. "</div> 
    <div id='price'> ". $row["avg_price_7_days"]. "</div>
    </div>";
```

I tried this, does not seem to work. TIA

Comment: You didn't close the last " in your `echo` command, nor end the statement with a ;

Comment: Sorry. I did, but just didn't post the code. Updated the question

Comment: Oic, thanks for updating. So then, what's the current output? "Does not seem to work" is awfully vague.

Comment: Do you get an error or blank page?

Comment: The output can be seen at http://csgo-house.com/withdrawscript.php   . If you inspect you will sea the <div> do not have background pictures

Comment: Does it work without these \ you put before the single quotes in your background property's url? I don't think they are needed.

Comment: remove quotes and add width and height for this div (in CSS). Remember id should be unique. use class if you want (or id with number).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be strictly within the first `div`. Try changing it to this:

```
"<div id='wtile' style='background:url(http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/". $row["icon_url_large"] . ");'> [...other divs]
```

Quoting the `url` value is optional and seems to be only making the code more confusing in this case.

**EDIT:**

Also, I accessed the link you provided in the comments and the values in `$row["icon_url_large"]` look really odd and don't even seem to have an extension (e.g. png). Make sure they refer to valid image files.

Comment: Tired that, it did not produce a background image on the div. This is the html it echoed `style="background:url(http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FA957PHEcDB9_9W7hIyOqPv9NLPFqWdQ-sJ0xOzFpN2h0QDj_0ttNmnwIoDHcFVqNFjZ-AC2lbq-1pLou5_MyXVkv3I8pSGK_P3OCnU);"`

Comment: I was just editing my answer to note that. This crazy value in `$row["icon_url_large"]` doesn't have an extension, so it doesn't seem to refer to a valid image file.

Comment: It is strange but they dont have an extenstion. They do load valid images although.. Another site used the same.. Another site had ' and ' before and after the link `style="background:url(http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJB496klb-GkvP9JrbummpD78A_3LGXrI-i31fm_Uc5MW_3I4LDelc2YQmF-FPtl7_uh8PtupTMn3pnvD5iuyj-_v0pRA);"` You see, this loads an image. How can I add ' without it being read as " by php

Comment: Just pasted this URL in my browser and all I get is a blank page. This really doesn't seem an URL which will give you an image. A good test to do would be to do the changes I suggested and replace this URL with some URL that you are sure to give you an image. Here's a random example: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100113135842/starwars/images/4/4e/PurplePlanet-FT.jpg. Check if this image will be rendered in your div's background.